# Excel IF formulas correction?

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I am trying to apply different formulas based on the range a number is in.  Can anyone help me correct this formula?

```
=If(AND(B4>0,B4 < 50000), 0, IF(AND(B4>49999.99,B4 < 100000),((B4-50000)*0.0275*2/3), IF(AND(B4>99999.99,B4<150000),(B4*.02+1850),IF(AND(B4>149999.99,B4<250000),(B4*.07/3+2850),IF(B4>249999.99),(B4*.08/3+5185)))))
```

In other words, if number is 0-50k, apply one formula, if 50k-100k, apply different formula, etc.

Any ideas how to make it work?  Thank you!

Comment: What's wrong with the one you have? What's the error?

Comment: Are all your numbers positive?

Comment: unbalanced parantheses. It should end like `,IF(B4>249999.99,(B4*.08/3+5185))))))`

Answer (score 3):

When daisy chaining If statements excel will look at them in order and as soon as one is true it stops looking.

Given that, we do not need to bracket each and every if.

```
=IF(B4 < 50000, 0, IF(B4 < 100000,(B4-50000)*0.0275*2/3, IF(B4<150000,B4*0.02+1850,IF(B4<250000,B4*0.07/3+2850,B4*0.08/3+5185))))
```

If it is less than 50000 then the first will be true and excel will not look at the rest of the statement.

If the number is 75000 then the first will be false and excel will move the next which will be true and excel will stop looking.

Knowing this we can avoid the AND() which just muddies the water.

Then the last formula we do not need an IF statement at all.  If it is greater than 250000 all four will resolve false and the end formula will fire.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are dealing only with numbers, you might find it easier to deal with boolean math instead of nested `if()` functions.

Using this technique we have a condition that is either `TRUE` or `FALSE` which is the same as `1` or `0`. So our conditions that would have been written like:

```
If(condition, result_if_true)
```

Would be, instead, written like:

```
(condition*result_if_true)
```

If our result_if_true is `B4+1` and `B4` equals `5` as an example and our condition is true, then:

```
(1*(B4+1))=(1*(5+1)) = 6
```

otherwise we get:

```
(0*(B4+1))=(0*(5+1)) = 0
```

You can add a bunch of these `(condition*result_if_true)` statements together instead of the nested `if()` formulas. In your case:

```
=(AND(B4>0,B4 < 50000) * 0) + (AND(B4>49999.99,B4 < 100000) * ((B4-50000)*0.0275*2/3)) + (AND(B4>99999.99,B4<150000) * (B4*.02+1850)) + (AND(B4>149999.99,B4<250000) * (B4*.07/3+2850)) + ((B4>249999.99) * (B4*.08/3+5185))
```

I like to use multiple lines in the formula bar when these start to get nasty:

```
=(AND(B4>0,B4 < 50000) * 0) + 
 (AND(B4>49999.99,B4 < 100000) * ((B4-50000)*0.0275*2/3)) + 
 (AND(B4>99999.99,B4<150000) * (B4*.02+1850)) + 
 (AND(B4>149999.99,B4<250000) * (B4*.07/3+2850)) + 
 ((B4>249999.99) * (B4*.08/3+5185))
```

It's a lot easier now to keep track of your opening and closing parantheses so you don't end up with a big mess. Also, back in Excel 2003 you could only nest 7 IF's deep and this is a great way around it. I believe now you can go 64 and may god have mercy on your soul should you near that limit.